# SQL BCP import - Varied column length merging data

Tags: sql-server, csv, bcp

Using BCP to upload a CSV file into SQL Server I encounter an issue where the first 4 rows wrap into 2 rows, with the remaining data uploading without an issue. The last column of the 1st row merges with the the 1st entry of the second row along with an enter (which looks like a space in SQL, displays as an enter in notepad).

I believe this is occurring due to the source file (csv) omitting commas. I don't want to load the file in Excel first.

e.g. Input

```
apple,orange,square,triangle [CRLF]
apple,orange,square,triangle,circle [CRLF]
apple,orange,square [CRLF]
apple,orange,square,triangle,circle,1,2,3,4,5,6,7  [CRLF]
apple,orange,square,triangle,circle,1,2,3,4,5,6,7  [CRLF]
apple,orange,square,triangle,circle,1,2,3,4,5,6,7  [CRLF]
apple,orange,square,triangle,circle,1,2,3,4,5,6,7  [CRLF] etc
```

e.g. Output

```
apple,orange,square,triangle apple,orange,square,triangle,circle,apple,orange,square,triangle,circle
apple,orange,square apple,orange,square,triangle,circle,1,2,34567
apple,orange,square,triangle,circle,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
apple,orange,square,triangle,circle,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 etc
```

My BCP code is as follows:

```
SET @command = 'bcp click_energy_reporting.dbo.tmp in \\Server\FileLocation\Combine.csv  -f \\Server\FileLocation\format_SPA1.txt -T'
```

And I have tried incorporating the row terminator, but I continue to get the same result. 
`-r \r`

My format file uses a comma for the row delimiter.

Comment: Have you tried as a tab delimited file instead? BULK
INSERT #test1 
FROM 'd:\111.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
);

Comment: Also, I've looked into bcp command lines and you could potentially have a format file. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms178129.aspx

Comment: @WickedFan I'm using a format file, delimited with commas "," and ending in "\r\n". I've tried various combinations of the ending "\r\n".

Comment: In your command you are not telling `BCP` what your row-terminator is. The default is just a newline (`\n`). Use `-r` option to specify something different if needed. The default column seperator is tab (`\t`), use the `-t` option to specify something different.

Comment: Personally I think it's best to use `\t` as field seperator (column seperator) and `\r\n` as the row terminator. With these seperators you can simply use the `-c` option of `BCP`.

Comment: @TT. I've tried changing the BCP code as suggested, however I still encounter the same error. Here is the updated code 'bcp click_energy_reporting.dbo.tmp in \\10.0.0.5\SQL_Upload\BCP\Accruals\Combine.csv  -f \\10.0.0.5\SQL_Upload\BCP\Accruals\format_SPA.txt -r \r\n -t \t -T'

Comment: You can drop the `-r \r\n -t \t` and instead specify `-c`. That does mean however you need tabs as field seperators (your question has comma's as seperators). Also, use a HEX editor to make absolutely sure the rows end with `\r\n`.

Comment: I've checked in Notepad++ and can clearly see the rows end CRLF. I've also attempted using the -c and omitting a format file but this also yielded the same result.

Comment: What SQL Server version are you using? I will try and reproduce this when I have some time free.

Comment: @TT I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce you problem (SQL Server 2008 R2). However the import fails for the lines that don't have a column for each value. So I padded each line with enough tabs for each column

The test table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test_table](
    [f1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [f2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [f3] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [f4] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [f5] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [n1] [int] NULL,
    [n2] [int] NULL,
    [n3] [int] NULL,
    [n4] [int] NULL,
    [n5] [int] NULL,
    [n6] [int] NULL,
    [n7] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The test data which I put in a file `C:\testfile.txt` (image to highlight the tabs & CRLF):

[image: The data file highlighting tabs & CRLF]

The raw data:

```
apple   orange  square  triangle                                
apple   orange  square  triangle    circle                          
apple   orange  square                                  
apple   orange  square  triangle    circle  1   2   3   4   5   6   7
apple   orange  square  triangle    circle  1   2   3   4   5   6   7
apple   orange  square  triangle    circle  1   2   3   4   5   6   7
apple   orange  square  triangle    circle  1   2   3   4   5   6   7
```

The command I used to import the data to the test table:

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(8000);
SET @cmd='BCP TEST_TT.dbo.test_table in C:\testfile.txt -c -T';
EXEC master.sys.xp_cmdshell @cmd;
```

The result for `SELECT*FROM test_table`:

```
+-------+--------+--------+----------+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|  f1   |   f2   |   f3   |    f4    |   f5   |  n1  |  n2  |  n3  |  n4  |  n5  |  n6  |  n7  |
+-------+--------+--------+----------+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| apple | orange | square | triangle | NULL   | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| apple | orange | square | triangle | circle | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| apple | orange | square | NULL     | NULL   | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| apple | orange | square | triangle | circle | 1    | 2    | 3    | 4    | 5    | 6    | 7    |
| apple | orange | square | triangle | circle | 1    | 2    | 3    | 4    | 5    | 6    | 7    |
| apple | orange | square | triangle | circle | 1    | 2    | 3    | 4    | 5    | 6    | 7    |
| apple | orange | square | triangle | circle | 1    | 2    | 3    | 4    | 5    | 6    | 7    |
+-------+--------+--------+----------+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Success!

Comment: PS: the reverse command to output resulted in the same file as the input (`DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(8000);
SET @cmd='BCP TEST_TT.dbo.test_table out C:\testfile2.txt -c -T';
EXEC master.sys.xp_cmdshell @cmd;`)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. You had mentioned that you had "padded each line with enough tabs for each column". This is the crux of my problem. I'm trying to find a way of using BCP so that the file padding isn't required (or worst case automating the padding of the file). I can pad the file by opening in Excel, but then I need to make a variety of formatting changes to ensure the data isn't stripped.

Comment: @PaulC When I tried that, I mean not padding, the lines that were not padded were not imported. Perhaps you could tweak the export options of the process that generated the file?